# Fixing nginx 1.4.6 dependency on old openssl version (libssl0.9.8)?

Tags: 12.04, nginx, ssl, openssl, tls

I'm trying to enable TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 instance w/ nginx 1.4.6, but this version of nginx is dependent upon `libssl0.9.8`, even though the newest version of OpenSSL is installed (1.0.1).

How can I resolve this so I can enable TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I resolve this so I can enable TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2?

It sounds like there are two issues in play. First is `nginx` related; and second is `openssl` related. There could be a third, and that's Amazon.

**nginx**

`nginx` can be built with OpenSSL. When it is, its built with the version of OpenSSL provided by the platform. Ubuntu 12.04 provides OpenSSL 1.0.1, and not 0.9.8. So you'll need to confirm that you are actually using 0.9.8 in `nginx`.

To verify the version of OpenSSL used by `nginx`, issue `ldd nginx`. For example here's the `openssl` executable's dependency (I don't use `nginx`, so I don't have it installed. You should swap in `nginx` for `openssl`):

```
$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
$ ldd /usr/bin/openssl 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff69ff000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f136424f000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f1363e58000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1363c53000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f1363a3c000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f13636b1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f13644c6000)
```

In the above, `libcrypto` and `libssl` are OpenSSL.

From the above, you can check the packages like at [libssl.so.1.0.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libssl1.0.0). Below, the 1.0.1 is OpenSSL's version

```
* Package: libssl1.0.0 (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.11)
* ...
```

**OpenSSL**

The lack of TLS 1.1 and 1.2 is probably due to Ubuntu's security team disabling the protocol versions in an effort to promote interoperability. See [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: OpenSSL downlevel version and does not support TLS 1.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576).

**Amazon**

Amazon may be providing images that are further modified. So the discussions about `nginx` and `openssl` might not apply or be wrong, depending on what Amazon did (or did not) do.

---

If you don't like the `nginx` as provided by the platform (either Ubuntu or Amazon), then you can try `nginx`'s PPA. See [nginx - Ubuntu PPA](http://wiki.nginx.org/Install).

You can also build it from sources. Be sure to install OepnSSL's developer package (`libssl-dev`). You'll need two or three additional packages, IIRC.

---

Sorry to bring in the bug report. That will probably cause this question to be closed. Please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

from the looks of it, you should submit a bug to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+filebug :)

you should also check: http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=354