# TLS 1.2 with Ubuntu 14.04 and Nginx

Tags: server, nginx, ssl, https

For a website of mine (https://brejoc.com) I wanted to set up a decent HTTPS configuration that would also support TLS version 1.2. Most of the modern browsers support that by now. So I generated a certificate with StartSSL. Everything but Nignx 1.8.0-1+trusty1 comes from the official repositories. Nginx was installed from Launchpad (http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu). OpenSSL version 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15 should be fine too.

The relevant part of the Nginx config looks like this:

```
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:EECDH:EDH:!MD5:!RC4:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!CAMELLIA:!ECDSA:!DES:!DSS:!3DES:!NULL;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
```

Checking the website with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest tells me, that TLS1.2 is not supported. I've tried several other cipher combinations, but nothing worked. The cipher list of https://cipherli.st/ won't work at all.

Comment: I was just digging around and found an answer to a related question for Ubuntu 12.04: http://askubuntu.com/a/441638/43783
There was mentioned that Nginx might very well be linked against an other OpenSSL version and that also seems to be true for this version. It is not linked against the installed version 1.0.1, but 1.0.0.

Comment: You need to research your information.  The `libssl-dev` is a build-dep. It's 1.0.1.  You need to give us more information.  Error logs from nginx'serror logs, etc.  And a copy of your config would be nice too, sanitized to remove secret information.

Comment: Using the SSL sections you've stated here, a valid SSL certificate, and the same PPA and OS on Ubuntu 14.04 locally, I get these results from an SSL Testing script:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/12450334/plain/

Comment: I've been [checking the shared lib dependencies](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12450983/) - and there libssl 1.0.0 is included. That raised some suspicions. Here is the complete [Nginx-config](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12450954/). And the ouput from `apt-cache policy openssl` and `apt-cache policy nginx nginx-common`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12450954/ http://paste.ubuntu.com/12450976/
The error logs are clean. Nothing that would give any indiacation that someting is wrong.

Comment: [Package results on an actual Ubuntu system](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12451355/plain/).  Take a look at the output of `apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0`, if it's `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15` installed, the library there is `libssl` 1.0.1.

Comment: Also include *actual* errors and such output...  like the DM I sent via twitter asked for.

Comment: @ThomasW. You are right; `libssl1.0.0` is `1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15`. But there are no actual errors. The error log `brejoc.com.error_ssl.log` is empty. There is just stuff from other vhosts in the global log. TLS1.2 just does not work. Oh, and I've just seen that TLS1.1 isn't working either. I don't get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29281/discussion-between-thomas-w-and-brejoc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through chat, we discovered that all but one site config had `ssl_protocols TLSv1;` in their configurations. Just one had `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;` in the site config. We removed them all, and had `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` defined with `ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;` which appears to have solved their issues.

Comment: Just one quick annotation. According to the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_protocols) both should be possible; the context for `ssl_protocols` can be `http` and `server`. But writing those settings once into the `nginx.conf` saves time and work.

Comment: I've found the [ticket addressing this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/766). It is only possible to use different SSL protocols on distinct ports. Sadly this is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @brejoc Sadly they were unable to reproduce and therefore the issue was invalidated...